# XEN VPS wrong memory?

Tags: linux, centos, memory, xen, memory-usage

I ordered a VPS on XEN platform with 1 GB of memory. CentOS 6.6

uname -a

```
Linux vps 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 9 20:57:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I checked the amount of memory:

```
cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:         667536 kB
MemFree:          211084 kB
Buffers:           12880 kB
Cached:           304484 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           135240 kB
Inactive:         192692 kB
Active(anon):      10572 kB
Inactive(anon):      124 kB
Active(file):     124668 kB
Inactive(file):   192568 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048572 kB
SwapFree:        1048572 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         10588 kB
Mapped:             8408 kB
Shmem:               132 kB
Slab:              39156 kB
SReclaimable:      20188 kB
SUnreclaim:        18968 kB
KernelStack:         736 kB
PageTables:         1804 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1382340 kB
Committed_AS:      63000 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       43944 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359693268 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:    10485760 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB
```

Its look like 512MB of memory.
Top:

```
Mem:    667536k total,   456708k used,   210828k free,    12888k buffers
```

I asked the tech support and was told:

> This is normal. this is due to us using the latest Xen 4.x.x Versions for performance enhancements which unfortunately can cause this anomaly
>   You can verify you have the correct memory information with the following command:
>   cat /proc/meminfo
>   This will produce something that looks like this:
>   ...
>   ...
>   At the bottom you will see ‘DirectMap4k’ this is the actual amount of RAM your VPS has allocated and can use.
>   Using the above example, take ‘DirectMap4k: 524288 kB’ divide the 524288 > kB by 1024 to convert it to megabytes and you get 512, yet the old free > -m command takes its info from the MemTotal line near the top which is not actually what you system is able to use.

Please tell me it's right? Can I use 1 GB of memory?

Comment: Can you please run `cat /proc/xen/balloon` and append the output to your question?

Comment: No such file /proc/xen/balloon